# How to select the latest of rows matching specific criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got rows with an increasing id, an item number and a status code. Over time new entries can be added for the same item until one gets added with status 0. 99% of items will only have a single status entry, which is 0.

I'd like to obtain the rows with the latest status, but only for items which did not reach status 0. I feel like I may be missing some simple solution here.

I can use a subqueries like:

```
Select ... From (
  Select max(id), item, status
  From updates
  Group by item
  Having status <> 0
) Where not exists (select 1 from updates u2 where u2.item = updates.item and u2.status=0)
```

to exclude items where the status was not 0, but reached 0 at some point. But that seems pretty inefficient.

I could also drop `having` and just filter out `status=0` in the outer SELECT, but items overwhelmingly have only the status 0 entry, so that's not very efficient either.

Since I only need to look through the table once, a cursor solution could be efficient, but I'd like to stick to simple queries if possible.

What other options am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I used a CTE to list all items which status is zero. Then I did a left join from your query to that CTE to eliminates all items which are listed in the CTE

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

```sql
WITH updates_status_zero 
AS
(
    SELECT item
    FROM updates
    WHERE status = 0
)

SELECT MAX(id), item, status
FROM updates
LEFT JOIN updates_status_zero
    ON updates.item = updates_status_zero.item
WHERE updates_status_zero.item IS NULL
GROUP BY item
```

CTE are usually preferred due to their simplicity to read and understand, also they can provide faster execution of your query

Answer (score 0):

You could use row_number

```
Declare @testTable Table (ID int, Item varchar(30), ItemStatus int);
 Insert Into @testTable (ID, Item, ItemStatus)
 Values (1, 'Item 1', 1)
      , (1, 'Item 1', 2)
      , (1, 'Item 1', 3)
      , (2, 'Item 2', 0)
      , (2, 'Item 2', 1)
      , (2, 'Item 2', 2)
      , (2, 'Item 2', 3)
      , (3, 'Item 3', 0)
      , (4, 'Item 4', 0)
      , (5, 'Item 5', 9)
      , (5, 'Item 5', 99);

   With itemData (ID, Item, ItemStatus, rownum)
     As (
 Select ID
      , Item
      , ItemStatus
      , row_number() over(Partition By ID Order By iif(ItemStatus = 0, 100, ItemStatus) desc)
   From @testTable
        )
 Select *
   From itemData
  Where rownum = 1
    And ItemStatus <> 0;
```

If the row has a 0 - that row will be row 1, so we can exclude those rows where the row number = 1 and Status = 0.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use window functions here, to calculate the latest row and whether `status=0` per `Item`.**

It's unclear what you mean by "latest", I've use `ORDER BY u.Id DESC` but you may want some other ordering.

```sql
SELECT id, item, status
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        isStatus0 = COUNT(CASE WHEN u.status = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY u.Item),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.Item ORDER BY u.Id DESC)
    FROM updates u
) u
WHERE u.rn = 1 AND u.isStatus0 = 0;
```